# Python - Replace last Octet in IP Address from list

Tags: python

I have a list of IP addresses where I want to replace the last octet of an IP Address with `0/24`

So a list of:

```
192.168.1.15
178.155.1.87 
5.26.95.136
```

Would become a list of:

```
192.168.1.0/24
178.155.1.0/24
5.26.95.0/24
```

Comment: Please edit the code you’ve written to try solve this into your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
cidr_list = []
for host in sorted_list:
    host = host[:host.rfind('.')+1] + '0/24'
    cidr_list.append(host)
```